# How do i know the service status in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In my ansible coding i want to know the status of the service like `service httpd status` (service is runngin or not) the result would be store in to variable. Using that status i will use some other code in ansible.

I am using ansible service module there is no option for status. If i use the shell module i got this warning

`[WARNING]: Consider using service module rather than running service`

so is it any other module doing to get service status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no standard module to get services' statuses.

But you can suppress warning for specific `command` task if you know what are you doing:

```
- command: service httpd status
  args:
    warn: false
```

I've posted a quick [note](https://ansibledaily.com/avoid-ansible-command-warnings/) about this trick a while ago.

Comment: here httpd service start it will work good. if service is stop i got error.

Comment: if `service` command exits with non-zero exit-code, you should handle it with `failed_when: false` for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the service_facts module.

For example, say I want to see the status of Apache.

```
- name: Check for apache status
  service_facts:
- debug:
    var: ansible_facts.services.apache2.state
```

The output is:

```
ok: [192.168.blah.blah] => {
"ansible_facts.services.apache2.state": "running"
}
```

If you would like to see all of them, you can do that by just going two levels up in the array:

```
var: ansible_facts.services
```

The output will list all the services, and will look like this (truncated for the sake of brevity):

```
 "apache2": {
        "name": "apache2", 
        "source": "sysv", 
        "state": "running"
    }, 
    "apache2.service": {
        "name": "apache2.service", 
        "source": "systemd", 
        "state": "running"
    }, 
    "apparmor": {
        "name": "apparmor", 
        "source": "sysv", 
        "state": "running"
    }, 
    etc,
    etc
```

I am using Ansible 2.7. Here are the docs for that module: [Click here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html)

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of starting a service and then checking status using service facts, in my example you have to register the variable then output it using debug var and pointing to the correct format in the json chain resulting output:

```
## perform start service for alertmanager

- name: Start service alertmanager if not started
  become: yes
  service:
    name: alertmanager
    state: started

## check to see the state of the alertmanager service status

- name: Check status of alertmanager service
  service_facts:
  register: service_state
- debug:
    var: service_state.ansible_facts.services["alertmanager.service"].state
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully [service: allow user to query service status #3316](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/3316) will be merged into the core module soon.

You can patch it by hand using this [diff to system/service.py](https://github.com/ritzk/ansible-modules-core/commit/ab4c9c226e94371c2b60aab57ef5b0a76f75a74b)

Here's my diff using ansible 2.2.0.0. I've run this on my mac/homebrew install and it works for me.

This is the file that I edited: `/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.2.0.0_2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/service.py`

```
@@ -36,11 +36,12 @@
         - Name of the service.
     state:
         required: false
-        choices: [ started, stopped, restarted, reloaded ]
+        choices: [ started, stopped, status, restarted, reloaded ]
         description:
           - C(started)/C(stopped) are idempotent actions that will not run
-            commands unless necessary.  C(restarted) will always bounce the
-            service.  C(reloaded) will always reload. B(At least one of state
+            commands unless necessary.  C(status) would report the status of
+            the service C(restarted) will always bounce the service.
+            C(reloaded) will always reload. B(At least one of state
             and enabled are required.)
     sleep:
         required: false
@@ -1455,7 +1456,7 @@
     module = AnsibleModule(
         argument_spec = dict(
             name = dict(required=True),
-            state = dict(choices=['running', 'started', 'stopped', 'restarted', 'reloaded']),
+            state = dict(choices=['running', 'started', 'stopped', 'status', 'restarted', 'reloaded']),
             sleep = dict(required=False, type='int', default=None),
             pattern = dict(required=False, default=None),
             enabled = dict(type='bool'),
@@ -1501,6 +1502,9 @@
     else:
         service.get_service_status()

+    if module.params['state'] == 'status':
+        module.exit_json(state=service.running)
+
     # Calculate if request will change service state
     service.check_service_changed()
```